# Laravel Seed - Argument 1 must be array, string given

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have the following code in a seeder:

```
public function develop_run()
{
    echo "Running ParentUsersTableSeeder\r\n";

    DB::table('parent_users')->truncate();

    $faker = Factory::create('en_AU');
    $rand = rand(100, 300);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rand; $i++) {

        $email = $faker->email;

        // Create the new user
        $parentUser = ParentUser::create([
            'first_name'            => $faker->firstName,
            'last_name'             => $faker->lastName,
            'email'                 => $email,
            'country_id'            => rand(1, 209),
            'last_access_at'        => Carbon::today(),
        ]);

    }
}
```

I cannot understand why the seed fails (at the `$parentUser =` step) with:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/vagrant/src/facultyenews/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 681
```

The items each individually show correctly if I `dd()` them. I have other seeds with the same syntax working perfectly, so I assume it is a simple screw up, but I cannot find it.

Any ideas welcome.

---

Results of `dd()`:

```
dd($email);
"xlueilwitz@yahoo.com"

dd($faker->firstName);
"Seamus"

dd($faker->firstName);
"Jones"
```

---

From another seeder in the same project, this works:

```
private function createRows($school, $role) {

    $faker = Factory::create('en_AU');
    $firstName = $faker->firstName;
    $lastName = $faker->lastName;
    $email = $firstName.'_'.$lastName.'@'.$school->website;

    // Preset Users and Schools
    $school_user = SchoolUser::create([
        'first_name'        => $firstName,
        'last_name'         => $lastName,
        'email'             => $email,
        'password'          => bcrypt('a'),
        'validated_email'   => 1,
        'validated_at'      => Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(0, 30)),
        'last_login_at'     => Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(0, 30)),
    ]);

    // Preset Users and Schools
    SchoolRoleUser::create([
        'school_user_id'    => $school_user->id,
        'school_id'         => $school->id,
        'role_id'           => $role->id,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: can you post the ouput of dd?

Comment: Hi @Exprator I added the dd results. It is failing at the `create` statement. So my `dd()` above are placed straight after the `$email =` statement. If placed after the `create` statement, then I get the error above.

Comment: bro can you try one thing? just remove the last two inserts. keep name lastname and email and try once

Comment: Same result. I removed `country_id` and `last_access_at` and the `parameterize()` error still happens.

Comment: ok got it. remove the strings and only keep the faker objects. like ([$faker->firstname,so on]) you dont need to mention the field names. go for it. it will solve your error

Comment: I removed the `email` entry, but it fails with the same error.

Comment: try to`dd()` the entire array you pass to `create()`. should give you a clue